# Can I define an interface for an enum in Google Closure?

Tags: google-closure

In Google Closure javascript, I can define the interface for a class with something like

```
/**
 * An object that implements this does fantastic, wonderful things. 
 * @interface
 */
name.space.for.project.SomeInterface = {};

/**
 * Some method that does something.
 * @param {number} foo
 * @return {string} Some fantastic, wonderful string.
 */
name.space.for.project.SomeInterface.prototype.doSomething =
    function(foo) {};
```

Can I somehow declare an interface for an enum, but not implement the enum? And then implement the enum in a separate file as usual? Like this?

```
/**
 * Enumerates event types.
 * @enum {string}
 * @implements {name.space.for.project.SomeEnum}
 */
name.space.for.project.SomeEnum = {
    FOO: 1,
    BAR: 2
};
```

Comment: I'm unclear here.  What is "as usual" here?

An enum should be a terminal object, that is it should only have the enumerated value keys as properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are sayingAre you looking for a Java-style enumeration, where the enum is of objects?

That is possible.

```
/**
 * An object that implements this does fantastic, wonderful things. 
 * @interface
 */
name.space.for.project.SomeInterface = {};

/**
 * Some method that does something.
 * @param {number} foo
 * @return {string} Some fantastic, wonderful string.
 */
name.space.for.project.SomeInterface.prototype.doSomething =
    function(foo) {};

/**
 * Enumerates event types.
 * @enum {name.space.for.project.SomeInterface}
 */
name.space.for.project.SomeEnum = {
    FOO: new name.space.for.project.SomeInterface(),
    BAR: new name.space.for.project.SomeInterface()
};
```